# How do I hide videos from the homepage when using 'show full posts' (wordpress)

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I need to show full posts on the homepage but would like to hide videos as this is making a very slow load time. I still want the videos in the posts, just not showing on the homepage.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_the_content()` function for retrive data ([wordpress get_the_content documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/)) to get the post and then trim that [like this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007597/how-can-i-remove-iframe-tag-from-a-string) if you insered content like youtube embeded video. (The code inside the link trim all iframe, so if you have other iframe they can eliminate from view on homepage).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am not using iframes / embedded videos from Youtube. These are videos I have uploaded myself. How would I go about this?

Comment: So how do the videos get into the post content?  Are you embedding the videos you uploaded?

Comment: Yes I am embedding them in the post content using flowplayer.

Comment: from media in Worpress where I uploaded them.

Comment: I don't know flowplayer, but i found this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87909/how-to-retrieve-text-only-from-wp-content-not-from-wp-excerpt) that make what you want using `echo wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_content() );`, so you need to find the page that call `get_the_content();` and replace with that.